# Is ConstraintSet.connect() margin parameter in px or dp?

Tags: android, margin, pixel, density-independent-pixel, constraintset

```
val margin = 8
ConstraintSet().apply {
  connect(anId, ConstraintSet.START, anotherId, ConstraintSet.START, margin)
}
```

Is `margin` applied as pixels or density-dependent pixels?

Various articles scattered around the web and apocryphal knowledge seem not to agree on one or the other. I'm looking for official documentation or source evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The `margin` parameter should be supplied in pixels**.

I ended up tracing the `ConstraintSet.applyTo(ConstraintLayout)` down to `ConstraintSet.applyToInternal(ConstraintLayout)` and found that here, each child of a `ConstraintLayout` has its `LayoutParams` copied and passed to `ConstraintSet.Constraint.applyTo(LayoutParams)`. Which then copies all the parameters (without modification) from the `ConstraintSet.Constraint` into the `LayoutParams` and then assigns the modified `LayoutParams` back to the child. I think this is concrete evidence that the supplied margin parameters should follow the `LayoutParams` rules.

*in ConstraintSet.java*

> ```
>     this.applyToInternal(constraintLayout);
>     constraintLayout.setConstraintSet((ConstraintSet)null); }
> ```

*at `applyToInternal(ConstraintLayout)` declaration*

> ```
>     int count = constraintLayout.getChildCount();
>
>     //...
>
>     LayoutParams param;
>     for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
>         View view = constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);
>         //...
>         param = (LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
>         constraint.applyTo(param);
>         view.setLayoutParams(param);
>         //...
>     }
>
>     //...
> ```

*at `applyTo(LayoutParams)` declaration*

> ```
>     //...
>     param.leftMargin = this.leftMargin;
>     param.rightMargin = this.rightMargin;
>     param.topMargin = this.topMargin;
>     param.bottomMargin = this.bottomMargin;
>     //...
> ```

Comment: I'll be leaving this open just in case there's any other input. Otherwise, I'll accept my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The margin, padding, constraint ... APIs all work in pixels. If you have DPs, you have to convert those to pixels first.

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation that states this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Java/Kotlin work with `px`. There's no official documentation that I can find (or anything in the source code of `ConstraintSet` or `Constraint`) that says this outright.

If you look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#7992) for `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`, however, you will find this code:

> ```
> public MarginLayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
>     ...
>     int margin = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
>                 com.android.internal.R.styleable.ViewGroup_MarginLayout_layout_margin, -1);
>     if (margin >= 0) {
>         leftMargin = margin;
>         topMargin = margin;
>         rightMargin= margin;
>         bottomMargin = margin;
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

It should be plain to see (from the call to `getDimensionPixelSize()`) that the units for `margin` here are `px`. I think it is reasonable to say that MarginLayoutParams is the "original" source of truth for margins, and I would generally expect things that emulate this behavior (like `ConstraintSet`) to follow the same pattern.

Note that `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` is a subclass of `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`.

Comment: I think you've arrived at the correct answer, however the `LayoutParams` of `ConstraintLayout` don't actually dictate anything about the functionality of `connect`.

Comment: Sure, but it would be very strange for two different pieces of one component to work two different ways. Considering that source code and experimentation show that it uses `px`, I'm not really sure what else would convince you.

Comment: I actually ended up tracing the `ConstraintSet.applyTo(ConstraintLayout)` down to `ConstraintSet.applyToInternal(ConstraintLayout)` and found that here, each child of a `ConstraintLayout` has its `LayoutParams` copied and passed to `ConstraintSet.Constraint.applyTo(LayoutParams)`. Which then copies all the parameters (without modification) from the `ConstraintSet.Constraint` into the `LayoutParams` and then assigns the modified `LayoutParams` back to the child. I think this is concrete evidence that the supplied `margin` parameters should follow the `LayoutParams` rules.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be a pixel. Use below function to convert `dp` to `px`.

```
public int dpToPx(int dp, Context context) {

        float density = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics()
                .density;
        return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation that states this?

Comment: As outlined in the chapter entitled Designing an Android User Interface using the Graphical Layout Tool, when setting sizes and positions in user interface layouts it is better to use density independent pixels (dp) rather than pixels (px). In order to set a position using dp it is necessary to convert a dp value to a px value at runtime, taking into consideration the density of the device display .

Comment: That tutorial explicitly indicates that the margin supplied should be dp and not pixels. Which is the opposite of what you're saying in your answer

Comment: In order to set a position using dp it is necessary to convert a dp value to a px value at runtime